# ArcGIS elevation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, elevation

I would like to get the elevation of different point in the digital elevation model means around 4000 points would any one please tell me how can it be possible.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail as to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the tool you are looking for: [Extract values to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm).